# Activa engine noise

Tags: engine, honda, motorcycle, noise, activa

My neighbor and I purchased an Activa 3g at the same time. When my bike is in idle (just after immediate start) as well in running condition, it sounds little bigger/ rough noisy like dub dub... Also, the accelerator is not smooth to hand. But I checked very carefully that my neighbour's bike is sounding very smooth and soft (not much noisy) while it in idle/running. I can hear my bike sound from 200 mars away also when it is coming to stop condition. This is not same with neighbor's bike. Even when their bike is close to us it's sound is not very audible. I can say definitely there is some difference in engine sound in my bike.

What could cause this and how can it be fixed? I told the Honda dealer while I went to the scheduled service and he said he did it. But he did not fix it, the noise is the same. What should I do to get soft and smooth sound from the engine?

Comment: Tried to find a specifications for this model, was wandering if there is available 4-stroke and 2-strokes.. That could be the answer! But no, only 4-strokes. So obviously it'll be an exhaust issue, or the variator weights worn and getting stuck. Shaik does your rear wheel turns when the scooter is on the stand and the rear wheel is up?

Answer (score 1):

> When my bike is in idle (just after immediate start) as well in running condition, it sounds little bigger/ rough noisy like dub dub...

---

> I can hear my bike sound from 200 mars away also when it is coming to stop condition. This is not same with neighbor's bike.

---

This is a telltale sign of an exhaust leak. Have the exhaust inspected for cracks or leaks, especially before the muffler.

Depending on where the size and position of the exhaust leak it can explain the non-smooth throttle response.

Comment: this is new one and half month old bike. Honda service people serviced it. I do not know whether they inspected for cracks or leaks. If I ask honda service guys, they will not respond. How can I check this?

Comment: Since this is a new bike, is it still under warranty? If it is it seems completely reasonable to ask the dealer to fix the problem. Do a test ride with them to show what the problem is, and then have them explain what they did to fix it and check it again with them after it is repaired.

Comment: @shaik apologies for the late response. If you cannot see where the issue is based on a visual inspection you could use soapy water in a spray bottle to spray areas where you suspect the leak occurs while the engine is running. If you see bubbles this would confirm a leak